# Having Cron job execute script in background and run for 15 hours

Tags: php, bash, cron

I have a PHP script that takes about 15 hours to run and I have to run it once a week. The script downloads and extracts the contents of a massive (70gb) CSV file into our database.

I need the script to start running every Sunday at 6 PM and to keep running until it's finished processing the file.

My plan is to create a bash file **cron.sh** that has the following:

```
nohup php /var/www/html/cron.php > /var/www/html/outputs/`date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`.log
```

And the cron being:

```
0 18 * * 0 /var/www/html/cron.sh
```

How would I be able to improve this?

Comment: Improve what? The time taken to put csv contents to db?

Comment: Sorry for not making it very clear. The part of the process where the cronjob exectues the PHP script.

Eg. should I be executing the php script directly from the cron job, etc.

Comment: Don't add details in comments. Instead, [edit] your question and put it there where it belongs. Your post should contain a *clear, specific problem description* and a *specific question related to that problem*. You've got neither.

Comment: Do you have a specific reason for using nohup, and for the intermediate `cron.sh` file?

Answer (score 2):

Remember to redirect stderr as well:

```
nohup php /var/www/html/cron.php > dir/stdout.log 2> dir/stderr.log
```

or if you prefer to merge them all in the same file:

```
nohup php /var/www/html/cron.php > dir/stdout.log 2>&1
```

The `2>&1` means redirect stderr to the same file stdout is using.

The rest is all fine, putting the command inside a shell script makes it more readable if the line is too long. Also if you later want to make the task do more things, it is easier to update the script file.

I would probably rename the cron.sh file to something more meaningful.

Comment: Also, by separating the commands to execute in a script file, a user with no cron privileges can still update the script (if he/she has the right file permissions).

Answer (score 2):

Since your OP asked "How would I be able to improve this" --  You didn't mention if you HAD to use PHP.

If the CSV is that large ..  I would create a bash file that does the same thing that your PHP file does (since you're already calling `cron.sh`).  You would have to change your PHP configuration to less than ideal settings to be able to run it efficiently.  IMHO straight bash is the way to go.  That way `nohup` can be bypassed entirely.

Meaning I would:

**1)** Create a login path for MySQL to securely connect to your db from the .sh file.  You can acheive this with the following command:

```
sudo mysql_config_editor set --login-path=client --host=yourHost --user=MySQL_user --password
```

You will be prompted for the MySQL password.

**2)** Once that is done, you can access MySQL in your bash file like such  AND create your logs all in the same file:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /place/where/you/want/the/csv/

wget http://your_file_location.com/csv/location/file.csv
# Or whatever you're doing to "download" it -- Just an example .. 

mysql --login-path=local infile=1 3parsfdb -e "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file.csv' INTO TABLE your_table FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','"

echo "Whatever you've collected" >> /var/www/html/outputs/`date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`.log
```

Of course that's just an example .. But you get the general idea.  Then store said bash file in a safe location.

**3)** Put your newly created bash file into the crontab.  You can use your user's `crontab`, or if the user doesn't have access to the bash file or directory you put it in, you can use root's `crontab` -- IE:

```
0 18 * * 0 /path/to/your/bash/file/BackupCSVToDB.sh
```

The saved overhead of not having to use PHP could save the run-time literally hours.